# Most common elements in list-column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using python / pandas.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
     date         id         my_column
0    31.07.20     128909     ['hey', 'hi']
1    31.07.20     128914     ['hi']
3    31.07.20     853124     ['hi', 'hello', 'hey']
4    30.07.20     123456     ['hey']
...
```

The dataframe over 1.000.000 rows long. I want the top 10 most common words in the my_column column.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), by default are values sorted, so for top10 need first 10 index values:

```
out = df['my_column'].explode().value_counts().index[:10].tolist()
```

Or you can use pure python solution for flatten and count top10:

```
from collections import Counter
from  itertools import chain

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(df['my_column']))
out = [a for a, b in c.most_common(10)]
```

Comment: Kind of works but the output doesn't give the single most common elements. It also gives several elements in combination. Kind of weird. Is it possible to get an output where only single elements are listed?

Comment: @BenW - Are in column lists? What is `print (df['my_column'].head(3).tolist())` ?

Comment: ["['hi', 'hey', 'hello', 'asd', 'fgh]", '[]', '[]']

Comment: @BenW - Is possible use `import ast` and `df['my_column'] = df['my_column'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` before my solution?

Comment: Gives the same output. EDIT: Nevermind made a mistake. works now.

Comment: @BenW - Same output if use `out = df['my_column'].apply(ast.literal_eval).explode().value_counts().index[:10].tolist()` vs `out = df['my_column'].explode().value_counts().index[:10].tolist()` ?

Comment: Thank you very much. Amazing help! Made my day!

Comment: Quick question: What does the .apply(ast.literal_eval) do? And another question: How do I make all the words lower case or alternatively make the code not distinguish between upper and lower case for the top list.

Comment: @BenW - It convert lists of strings to list of lists, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list), for lowercase `out = df['my_column'].apply(ast.literal_eval).explode().str.lower().value_counts().index[:10].tolist()`use

Comment: Thanks. I get a "ValueError: malformed node or string". The words in my data actually contain a "#" before every word. I think that may cause the error.

Comment: @BenW - hmm, it means already values are lists or some wrong values

Comment: Ah its because i applied the ast.literal_eval twice. My bad. Everything working perfectly now. Can i donate you some money for your help?

Comment: Feel free to send me your paypal or something in a message. Appreciate your help a ton!